# Can We download Zip for multiple txt files without downloading the txt fileS in java?

Tags: java, file, stream

Can we write into multiple txt files and download them directly  as zip (Without downloading txt files )

When we write in file it is done in physical file. But when we want to create zip of that reference it will consider the object file .

Is there any way to store data in object file then download it as zip .??

```
File file = new File("/Users/VYadav/Desktop/lex/sitemap.txt");  // creates local object
String zipFileName = "/Users/VYadav/Desktop/lex/zipname.zip";

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(file);  // creates a physical file on disk
pw.write("Hii");   // writes in physical file
pw.flush();

ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file.getName()); // Reads from local object (here data is not present) 

zos.putNextEntry(ze);
```

The out put of this code will be one txt file having "Hii" as data and a zip file containing a blank txt file .

because file is put into zip entry from  objet.

Is there any way to update our data in the object then download into zip folder ??

Comment: Can you provide bit more explanation on this ?

Comment: Hi Sambit, Thanks for your response . Acctually my requirement is to write in multiple files in loop.   Instead  of downloading all files as  txt I want to download them all as zip.   So Just wanted to know if there is any way to compress object file directly into zip then download it .?

Answer (score 0):

You can write Zip file with all the "zipped" files created on-the-fly.

Since you're talking about "downloading", I'll assume that you're in a webapp, and want to generate the zip file directly back to the client, so you need to create the `ZipOutputStream` against the response stream, not a file. E.g. in a `Servlet` webapp, you'd do it like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");

ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(zos);

zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Foo.txt"));
// write content of Foo.txt here, e.g.
out.println("Hello Foo");
out.flush();

zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Bar.txt"));
// write content of Bar.txt here, e.g.
out.println("Hello Bar");
out.flush();

zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Baz.png"));
// write content of Baz.png here, e.g. copy bytes from file on classpath
try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo.png")) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    for (int len; (len = in.read(buf)) > 0; )
        zos.write(buf, 0, len);
}

// Complete the zip file.
zos.finish(); // or zos.close()
```